# Close chat program or jframe when client writes 'bye'?

Tags: java, swing, chat

Can anayone give me a code to close the jframe or chat program when a client inputs 'bye'?

Comment: No. We are here to help, not to write code for who asks for it. [Freelancer](http://www.freelancer.com/) users do that.

Comment: Take a look to [How to write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
if(input.equals("bye"))
    System.exit(0);
```

Comment: where do i include that?

Comment: @user3485668 Wherever you have the user input available to check in this way!